# indoor avacado tree care

Tags: trees, indoors

I have an avacado tree that I grew from a pit. The tree is about a foot and a half tall and has 3 big green leaves on it. It's been the same way for about 3 months now and is not growing anymore leaves. The leaves that are there are drooping but big. Is there a problem with the tree or is this normal.

Comment: hello Linda.  Welcome.    Where are you located?  Is it winter at the moment?  Is it in a pot or in water?  Do you have a grow light for it?  Can you post some pictures? To add a picture hit the edit link below your question.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like its unhappy,
Plants usually slow down growth  for a number of reasons some of which are listed below:

1) low light amounts.

2) low nutrition.

3) wrong temperature or humidity.

4) infestation or diseases some times both at the same time.

5) dormancy as some plants need a some time being dormant but not all.

We need a photo or further info to accurately diagnose the issue.